# Karate doesn't check cases if expected number is a larger, how do I handle it?

Tags: karate, testcase

I have given match response as #number
But for a value of 15547786385661 the case just gets skipped.how do I handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be making some simple mistake. Try pasting the two lines below into a fresh scenario and see it work:

```
* def response = { foo: 15547786385661 }
* match response == { foo: '#number' }
```

Comment: The def part is passing but match response is getting skipped again.